# Using APCu on Travis CI, which runs Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, travis-ci

I have a Symfony-application which is dependent on APCu (`php5-apcu`). The server is running PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 15.04. APCu is required as a dependency through composer, i.e:

```
"require": {
    "ext-apc": "~4.0"
}
```

Which works great. Trying to get the application running on Travis-CI, isn't as smooth, since they run Ubuntu 12.04, which doesn't have the `php5-apcu` package, which yields:

> E: Unable to locate package php5-apcu

Installing `php-apc` doesn't satisfy the `ext-apcu` requirement, and I'd prefer not to promote deprecated packages.

Any suggestions on how to setup APCu on Travis CI? Preferably without manually downloading the package.

Comment: What about installing it from PECL? Travis-CI supports [installation from PECL](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Installing-additional-PHP-extensions) and APCu 4.0.7 can be installed without problems on 12.04 with PECL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily install the apcu extension from pecl.

Here is an example .travis.yml file:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6

before_script:
  - pear config-set preferred_state beta
  - yes '' | pecl install apcu

script:
  - cd tests/ && phpunit
```

If you need a more complex solution, for example multiple php versions, you should be able to easily adopt the solution from the doctrine/cache repository (https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/.travis.yml).
They run the tests against php 5.3 - 5.6 and hhvm with the following before_script:

```
[...]
before_script:
    - [...]
    - sh -c "if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != 'hhvm' && `php-config --vernum` -ge 50500 ]] ; then pecl config-set preferred_state beta; printf "yes\n" | pecl install apcu ; else echo 'extension="apc.so"' >> ./tests/travis/php.ini ;fi"
    - [...]
[...]
```

Happy testing

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Pecl installation was the way to go, edited your answer to include my specific installation process.